# GoSublime: No code completion for App Engine packages

Tags: google-app-engine, go, sublimetext2

I'm trying to get Sublime Text 2 set up so that it also serves code completion for the App Engine packages.

In my GoSublime User Settings I've got

```
{
        "shell": ["/bin/bash"],
        "env": {"GOPATH": "$HOME/gocode/:$HOME/src/go_appengine/goroot/src/"},
        "fmt_cmd": ["goimports"]
}
```

however, I cannot get code completion for the App Engine packages to work.

I have also symlinked darwin_amd64_appengine/ to darwin_amd64 in ~/src/go_appengine/goroot/pkg.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a quite lengthy discussion with the author of GoSublime, who was extremely helpful and we finally solved the problem.

You can follow along the many steps [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/issues/497).

Along the way the author fixes two minor bugs, so updating GoSublime might be all you need to do. In case this has helped you, please vote the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

To save other from visiting the issue Ralf linked to.
Here's what I change the `GoSublime` `Settings-User` to:

`GoSublime.sublime-settings`

```
{
  "use_legacy_imports": true,
  "installsuffix": "appengine",
  "env": {
    "GOPATH": "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot"
  }
}
```